# Copy files from AWS s3 sub folder to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy files out of a s3 bucket using azure data factory. Firstly I want a list of the directories.
Using the CLI I would use. {aws s3 ls }

From there I can determine from the list in a foreach an push that into a variable.

In adf, I have tried to use 'get metadata', although this works in theory. In practice there are 76 files in each directory and the loop is over 1.5m. This just isn't worth it, it takes far too long, especially as the directories only takes about 20 seconds for 20000 directories.

Is there a method to do this list. When creating the dataset we have a no permissions, however when we use specific location it does.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way of completing this task.
So to begin with I am using get metadata with the child option. It produces an array.
I push this into a string variable. With this variable you can then create a stored procedure to pick this apart, using openjson to get just the value. This can then be pulled apart further to get the directory names.
I then merge these into a table.
Using lookup I can then run another stored procedure to return the value I require from the table. This whole process runs in a couple of minutes.
Anyone who wants a further explanation, please ask, I will try and create a walk through to assist